# How do I make data from node's process.stdout.on stream globally accessible?

Tags: node.js, sockets

This is a js function in my server code that has a child process which streams data from a python script:

```
    var dataString = '';
sampleFunc = function(){
    var spawn = require('child_process').spawn,
        py = spawn('python', ['F:/sample.py']),
        data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9];

    py.stdout.on('data', function(data){
            console.log("before data write");
              dataString += data.toString();
            });

        py.stdout.on('end', function(){
            console.log("successful");
            dataStr = dataString;
              console.log(dataString);
            });

        py.stdin.write(JSON.stringify(data));
        console.log("inside stdin");    
        py.stdin.end();

};
```

Then i'm using socket.io to send this data to a client. But dataStr is always empty outside of stdout.

```
io.on('connection', function(socket){
sampleFunc();
console.log(dataStr);
console.log('a user connected');

});
```

I simply need to get the data coming into the stream at:

```
py.stdout.on('data', function(data){
                console.log("before data write");
                  dataString += data.toString();
                });
```

and be able to access it inside the socket code. Any help in solving this would be much appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

You just have to emit the data from the socket...?

```
py.stdout.on('data', function(data){
                console.log("before data write");
                  dataString += data.toString();
                  io.emit(dataString); 
                });
```

Comment: This works thanks. It didn't occur to me to use io.emit() inside the stream itself. But is it possible to use the data outside of it? When i try to assign it to a global variable, outside of the stream the variable remains empty.

Comment: that should probably be another question, but the generic answer is "it depends on scope and timing".  In general, it's unreliable to set a global variable from inside a callback,  b/c you never know it will be available when the code needing it wants it.  Better to have the code that needs it respond to an event of some kind.

Comment: Noted. Thanks a lot Paul :)